# How does connect take in mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps to create a higher order component?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I've been trying to figure out two things regarding redux

1. `mapDispatchToProps` is a function that takes in `dispatch` as an argument, where is `dispatch` defined? and
2. how does `connect` utilize `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` to create HOC(Higher Order Component) ?

If I understand correctly, connect is essentially a compositional function that takes the result of `mapDispatchToProps` and passes it to `mapStateToProps` then returns the result, which is a component, but how is it done?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `mapDispatchToProps` is a function that you will define. React-Redux calls your function with `dispatch` passed in as the first parameter. And that `dispatch`, in turn, comes from the `store` you provided to `<Provider />`.
2. `connect` takes the `mapState` and `mapDispatch` that you will define, and create the wrapper function that, in the most common cases:

   - run `mapState` with `state` every time your store changes
   - run `mapDispatch` once when the component is instantiated

   The returns of both of these functions will be merged into your wrapped component.

Seems that you'd like to figure out how it is done. [This Dan Abramov's gist](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/1d19088790e70ac32ea636c025ba424e) explains `connect` in a mental modal (simplified version of what it does).

Hope that helps!